# Clarification of Sperner's Lemma

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, definition, triangulation, simplicial-complex

From Graph Theory by Bondy, Murty[image]

---

Image from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_lemma)[image]

---

---

I don't see how the picture holds according to the definition from the Graph Theory book.

Specifically, the definition says to assign the colors to the vertices of the sub triangles so that each color is missing from one side of the triangle but appears on the other two sides. However, in the picture, I see triangles with red on all sides.

Are we only considering that the definition hold for $T$ only? That is, the outside edges only?

Comment: The definition only restricts how the edges of $T$ (which is the big triangle) are colored. It doesn't seem to restrict at all the sub-triangles.

Comment: The condition requiring colors missing from the sides is only talking about the whole triangle. So it's not clear where you think the picture violates that condition.

Comment: One edge of $T$ (the bottom) is missing red; another edge of $T$ (the left) is missing blue; the last edge of $T$ (the right) is missing green. That is all the definition means, no more and no less (the colours of the vertices of T itself are determined by these restrictions, so the part about "appearing on the other two sides" is redundant).